# Computing with nested values from subqueries in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope, subquery

I'm struggling for days now with the following issue in Laravel:

I've got three models:

- Equipment (has many batches)
- Batch (belongs to equipment, and a location, and has many transactions)
- Transaction (belongs to a batch)

In the batch model I have a scope to calculate the current quantity in that batch based on the transactions since the last transaction with the type "COUNT" (there are three types, COUNT, IN and OTU):

```
public function scopeWithCurrentQt($query)
{
    $query->addSelect(['current_qt' => Transaction::selectRaw('SUM(hospital_transactions.qt) AS qt_sum')
        ->whereColumn('batch_id', '=', 'hospital_batches.id')
        ->where('issued_at','>=',function ($subquery) {
            $subquery->select('hospital_transactions.issued_at')
                ->from('hospital_transactions')
                ->whereColumn('batch_id', '=', 'hospital_batches.id')
                ->where('hospital_transactions.type','=','COUNT')
                ->latest()
                ->take(1);
        })
    ])->withCasts(['current_qt' => 'integer']);

}
```

Now I want the Equipment model to calculate the total quantities based on the current quantities from the batches. In the code you also see a division in various locations, that's because there should be a distinction between those as well.

Now this can be achieved pretty easily by appending an attribute to the model:

```
public function getQtActualAttribute(): object
{
    $locations = $this->getHospitalStandardLocations();

    $qt_inventory = $this->batches->whereNotIn('location_id',$locations->raft)
        ->whereNotIn('location_id',$locations->fak)
        ->sum('current_qt');

    $qt_fak = $this->batches->whereIn('location_id',$locations->fak)
        ->sum('current_qt');

    $qt_raft = $this->batches->whereIn('location_id',$locations->raft)
        ->sum('current_qt');

    return (object) [
        'check' => $locations->ignore_fak ? $qt_inventory : $qt_inventory + $qt_fak,
        'inventory' => $qt_inventory,
        'fak' => $qt_fak,
        'raft' => $qt_raft,
        'total' => $qt_inventory + $qt_fak + $qt_raft
    ];
}
```

But the difficulty is, I can't filter on these values, unless I'm loading all the models, which is not preferable. So I came to thing, let's add a scope with subqueries as well.

I have tried A LOT of options. The latest version I have is this:

```
public function scopeWithQts($query){
        $locations = $this->getHospitalStandardLocations();

        $query->addSelect([
            'qt_inventory' => function ($query) use ($locations) {
                $query->selectRaw('sum(current_qt)')
                    ->from('hospital_batches')
                    ->whereNotIn('location_id', $locations->raft)
                    ->whereNotIn('location_id', $locations->fak)
                    ->whereColumn('equipment_id', 'hospital_equipment.id');
            },
            'qt_fak' => function ($query) use ($locations) {
                $query->selectRaw('sum(current_qt)')
                    ->from('hospital_batches')
                    ->whereIn('location_id', $locations->fak)
                    ->whereColumn('equipment_id', 'hospital_equipment.id');
            },
            'qt_raft' => function ($query) use ($locations) {
                $query->selectRaw('sum(current_qt)')
                    ->from('hospital_batches')
                    ->whereIn('location_id', $locations->raft)
                    ->whereColumn('equipment_id', 'hospital_equipment.id');
            }
        ]);

        return $query;
    }
```

But basically, all are resulting in the following error:
**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'current_qt' in 'field list'**

The function from the controller is the following:

```
$equipment = Equipment::with(['batches','batches.location'])
            ->orderByCode()
            ->withExpiryDates()
            ->withQts()
            ->when($expiryDates, function ($query) use ($expiringBefore){
                $query->whereHas('batches', function($query) use ($expiringBefore){
                    $query->expiringBefore($expiringBefore);
                });
            });
```

Anybody a suggestion how to solve this? Thanks!